# Setup nginx on GCP Windows server

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2012, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am newbie on GCP. Initially I was Created a Project on GCP then Create Instance (windows server) and then install Test app of nodejs. Simply I just want to Host my Project on GCP. Someone suggested me that first you have to do setup of nginx which is run on by default port 80.
Now I after successfull setup I have to use reverse proxy on nginx so that my Node app will run.

Like in Windows 10, we have to simple click on nginx download link. Then it will downloaded on drive and then we have to simply cut paste on C drive and then do some configuration on conf file. But I have no idea about the GCP Server.

If Anyone have knowledge about GCP hosting & all these related things then please guide me. Any Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows VM instance in GCP is the same as in a bare-metal computer. You would have to [RDP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance) into the Windows VM instance. Once you are connected to the VM server via RDP, then you may install and configure nginx. For more information on Windows VM instances, you may consult [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/).